# MySql get_lock for concurrency safe upsert

Tags: mysql, node.js, concurrency, locking, mutex

Writing an API in node.js with a mysql db and I am implementing a fairly standard pattern of:

```
If exists then update
else insert
```

This of course works fine until multiple simultaneous requests are made to the api at which point the `If exists` on request 2 can get executed before the insert of request 1, leading to two records instead of one.

I know that one way of dealing with this is ensure that the db has a constraint or key that prevents the duplicate record but in this case the rules that determine whether we should have an insert or update are more complicated and so the check needs to be done in code.

This sounded like a good case for using a mutex/lock. I need this to be distributed as the api may have multiple instances running as part of a pool/farm.

I've come up with the following implementation:

```
try {
     await this.databaseConnection.knexRaw().raw(`SELECT GET_LOCK('lock1',10);`);
     await this.databaseConnection.knexRaw().transaction(async (trx) => {
        const existing = await this.findExisting(id);
        if (existing) {
          await this.update(myThing);
        } else {
          await this.insert(myThing);
        }
     });

  } finally {
    await this.databaseConnection.knexRaw().raw(`SELECT RELEASE_LOCK('lock1');`);
}
```

This all seems to work fine and my tests now produce only a single insert. Although it seems a bit brute force/manual. Being new to mysql and node (I come from a c# and sql server background) is this approach sane? Is there a better approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is it sane? Subjective.

Is it technically safe?  It could be -- `GET_LOCK()` is reliable -- but not as you have written it.

You are ignoring the return value of `GET_LOCK()`, which is 1 if you got the lock, 0 if the timeout expired and you didn't get the lock, and NULL in some failure cases.

As written, you'll wait 10 seconds and then do the work anyway, so, not safe.

This assumes you have only one MySQL master.  It wouldn't work if you have multiple masters or Galera, since [Galera doesn't replicate `GET_LOCK()`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/mariadb-galera-cluster-known-limitations/) across all nodes.  (A Galera cluster is a high availability MySQL/MariaDB/Percona cluster of writable masters that replicate synchronously and will survive the failure/isolation of up to *(ceil(n/2) - 1)* out of *n* total nodes).

It would be better to find and lock the relevant rows using [`SELECT ... FOR UPDATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-locking-reads.html), which locks the found rows or, in some cases, the gap where they would be if they existed, blocking other transactions that are attempting to capture the same locks until you rollback or commit... but if that is not practical, using `GET_LOCK()` is valid, subject to the point made above about the return value.

Comment: Note that even when using `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` and a `SERIALIZABLE` transaction, the gap is not locked in the sense that 2 concurrent transactions will be able to SELECT the gap at the same time; one will *not* be waiting for the other. Only on `INSERT`, the waiting will occur, and if both TX try to insert the same row, a deadlock will occur and one of the transactions will be forcefully rolled back. So if you want to serialize your `SELECT ... INSERT` with a potentially non-existing row, and want to avoid deadlocks, then although it's a bit fiddly, `GET_LOCK()` is the only solution I know.